Sprite moving at insane speed and falling through objects in a Unity 2D Game
I have a model of a bug placed on top of blocks (Tilemap). The Tilemap has a Tilemap Collider component. When i launch the game, the bug moves fine, but after a few seconds it starts slightly falling under the floor, and later accelerating at insane speeds. Here is the code for the bug:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 50f;
    public Vector3[] positions;
    private int indexPosition;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (transform.position.x > GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position.x) {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true; }
        else {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false; }

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positions[indexPosition], speed/1000);
        

        if (transform.position == positions[indexPosition]) {

            if (indexPosition < positions.Length - 1) {

                indexPosition++;

            }

            else {

                indexPosition = 0;
                

            }

        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {

            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);

        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {

            Destroy(gameObject);

        }
    }
}

Note that i have 2 Vector3 values in my component, that are both correct and the bug should not glitch thorugh the floor
I tried asking my unity teacher, but 2 lessons passed and the issue remained
I expected the bug to move from one location to another

In general speed/1000 is still frame rate dependent .. why not make proper use of Time.delaTime ?

It sounds like you have a rigid body with gravity on.
I'm guessing your moveTowards
        if (transform.position == positions[indexPosition]) {

won't always achieve that equality. Then gravity starts getting bigger than your speed.
You likely don't need gravity if you are hardcoding its position with your positions array

Yeah Rigidbody is probably the issue, good catch! The transform will fight against it try to teleport the object but the Rigidbody maintains its velocity and over time gravity will accelerate it so it is falling faster than the MoveTowards can counter
